# How to add custom css and js files after certain default ones

Tags: head

We know that all css/js files added by `page.xml` in `default` handle are global, they're loaded in all pages.

When I add some css and js files in specific handle (eg. `catalog_category_default`), they're added to the top of head, before all global ones. But I want to add them AFTER.

How to add css/js after global files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By researching, I've found some answers and tutorials that suggest me to hack to Core code. Eg: add some additional functions like `addItemAfter($after, ...)`, `addItemFirst(...)`

But I think it's not ideal solution.

By looking into `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head` class, function `getCssJsHtml`, I found this line:

```
$lines[$if][$item['type']][$params][$item['name']] = $item['name'];
```

It means, css/js files are grouped by its condition. Files with same condition are added into the same group.

So, I think, you can use file's condition like a hook.

According to [MSDN document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx), you can use some conditional comments like this:

`<!--[if (gte IE 9) | (IEMobile)]><!-->`

Or if you want it to always return true, just use `<!--[if true]><!-->`

Let's go.

**First, declare the hooks.**

1. Create a blank js file (or css file). Eg: `skin/frontend/your_package/your_theme/js/blank.js`. Leave it empty content.
2. Open `app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/layout/page.xml`
3. In default handle (`<default translate="label" module="page">`), block `head`, seek to last current js files (or css files if you want), add:

`<action method="addItem">
    <type>skin_js</type>
    <name>js/blank.js</name>
    <params/>
    <if><![CDATA[<!--[if true]><!-->]]></if>
</action>`

You must to specify a file name, because it's just a hook, use a blank file, so it doesn't affect to performance, especially when you turn on Merge mode.

**Second, and last, use the hooks.**

In your specific handle, eg. `catalog_category_default` (Category page), add js/css file with the same condition you just declared.

`<reference name="head">
    <action method="addItem">
        <type>skin_js</type>
        <name>js/your.custom.js.file.js</name>
        <params/>
        <if><![CDATA[<!--[if true]><!-->]]></if>
    </action>
</reference>`

Now, load a category page and view it's source. You see:

```
<!--[if true]><!-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/skin/frontend/your_package/your_theme/js/blank.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/skin/frontend/your_package/your_theme/js/your.custom.js.file.js"></script>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Your custom file is loaded in the same condition with the hook. Because the hook is at bottom of default files, so your custom file is at bottom as well.

It's done.

P/s: I don't know if it's valid, but actually, you can use any condition, like this `<!--[if hook_one]><!-->`, `<!--[if hook_two]><!-->`

So, whenever you want to add js/css files into a desire place, just go to the root page (or parent page), declare a hook, then use it in custom handle. It's simple.